# Generating and using URLs as jscript variables

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-rewriting, createelement

I have now spent hours trying to figure out how you do this by reading other's posts - I even got a jsfiddle to work, but can't get this to work in my page.

I want to construct a URL to be used on a page multiple times, so that when I need to update the URL, I only need to do it in one place via a Javascript variable in the header.

I break the URL into two parts because one of the variables will nearly always be the same, but the other most often will be different on different pages.

For example, I declare in my header:

```
<script language="javascript" type=”text/javascript”>
function goSchedule()
{
var schedulePath = "http://[rootPath]/";
var scheduleFileName = "[extension to document].htm";
schedulePath = schedulePath + scheduleFileName;
document.getElementById('go').href= schedulePath;
}
</script>
```

And then I can't seem to figure out how to call it in the href. This doesn't work:

```
<p>Click the following link to test:<a href="javascript:goSchedule();" id="go">Test this link</a></p>
```

If you answer, please explain how the initial Javascript is created *and* how to properly call it so it becomes an active URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to replace the href attribute at the moment the user clicks the link.  I suggest you replace the href attribute once for all the link as soon as the page has finished loading.

Make sure you declare your function in the head section

```
<head>

<!-- Other head declarations ... -->

<script language="javascript" type=”text/javascript”>
function goSchedule() {
    var schedulePath = "http://[rootPath]/";
    var scheduleFileName = "[extension to document].htm";
    schedulePath = schedulePath + scheduleFileName;
    document.getElementById('go').href = schedulePath;
}
</script>
</head>
```

And then bind this method to the onload event of the body element like this

```
<body onload="goSchedule()">

    <!-- Other HTML Stuff Goes Here ... -->

    <p>Click the following link to test:<a href="javascript:void" id="go">Test this link</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

Here is the full html page:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Other head declarations ... -->

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function goSchedule() {
                var schedulePath = "http://support.mozilla.org/";
                var scheduleFileName = "en-US/products/firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct";
                schedulePath = schedulePath + scheduleFileName;
                document.getElementById('go').href = schedulePath;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="goSchedule()">

        <!-- Other HTML Stuff Goes Here ... -->

        <p>Click the following link to test:<a href="javascript:void" id="go">Test this link</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi seberenimer, thank you for this. I replaced my text with yours and tested with the two parts of the URL set to ... var schedulePath = "http://support.mozilla.org/"; AND
var scheduleFileName = "en-US/products/firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct";  The result doesn't work. I also tried with a simpler URL that doesn't have special characters, and it didn't work either. Do you know what might be happening?  -George

Comment: Also, I tested the page in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (all current versions).

Comment: No, I included it too. -George

Comment: These are the two paths I used for the mozilla test - I'll post in the next comment so you can see it in its entirety. - George

Comment: <script language="javascript" type=”text/javascript”>
function goSchedule()
{
var schedulePath = "http://support.mozilla.org/";
var scheduleFileName = "en-US/products/firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct";
 schedulePath = schedulePath + scheduleFileName;
 document.getElementById('go').href = schedulePath;
}
</script>

Comment: That's weird... the http:// got lost in the paste. The anchor script is just like yours, and I added the onload in the body tag too. - George

Comment: That's the bizarre thing... I started in jsfiddle and things work there, but not an actual page. I began thinking I'm not stating something properly in the header or I have wrongly created the reference in the anchor tag. I'll now go and try the file on a different computer. -George

Comment: Just finished moving the test file to a different computer, on a different domain, and the mozilla url test doesn't do anything. Thoughts? -George

Comment: I put the full page code in the answer and I realized maybe there is a problem with the **quotes** of the **type** attribute of the **script** tag in the head

Comment: Awesome! That was it! Thank you thank you! Your support IS VERY MUCH appreciated. - George

Comment: Didn't know to do that. Thanks. A future improvement to this idea will be to create an automated index that links to named anchors on a page so that each generated URL will go the right page and scroll down to the right spot. Not sure I want to try figuring that out now though! Again, thanks for your help! -George